# Is CPU instruction set version accounted for when I install pre-compiled distro?

Tags: kernel, compiling, cpu-architecture

I can have
`Intel Xeon E5-2620 v3` or `Xeon E5-2620 v2` on my system. The difference is instruction sets these two CPUs implement. Will Ubuntu server installer detect this difference and choose correct target arch, or I need compile the kernel myself?

Answer (score 1):

> The difference is instruction sets these two CPUs implement.

No, the difference is in the *extensions* to the instruction set that they implement. Both implement the [`x86-64`/`amd64` IS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64), and [the former](http://ark.intel.com/products/83352/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2620-v3-15M-Cache-2_40-GHz) has the AVX v2.0 extensions, whereas [the latter](http://ark.intel.com/products/75789/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2620-v2-15M-Cache-2_10-GHz) has just [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions).

> Will Ubuntu server installer detect this difference and choose correct target arch?

It can detect the version. However, irrespective of the version, the architecture is still `amd64`. And it's up to you to download the `amd64` images. As far as I can tell, there are no multiarch images. In practice, most pre-compiled distros don't bother about the version differences between CPUs - they all target the `amd64` IS.

> [Do] I need [to] compile the kernel myself?

You can, if you need to, but I don't see the point of it unless you're looking to extract every last bit of performance from the CPU or something. Then it's up to you to ensure your kernel stays updated.

Comment: Thanks. I think I need to put it this way, does kernel discriminate between CPU versions in order to squeeze "every last bit of performance"? I did grep the source code for haswell and ivybridge and I only found those cues in display/GPU related code, so I'm confused.

Comment: The kernel could have different code sections for different processors, but for the most part, it just uses the common IS targeted during compilation. I have to ask: why are you bothered about this?

Comment: There are benchmarks (e.g. http://www.pogolinux.com/blog/xeonv3/) revealing benefits of v3 IS. And since I'd like to maximize performance I am trying to address all possibilities.

Comment: @wick just get your individual apps to use the extensions. You don't have to get the kernel to do so.